# Map, lambda in Python 2 vs 3

Tags: python-3.x

I just switched from Python 2 to 3, but this code does not work. What is the problem, please advise.

```
a = [1, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8]
map(lambda x: x + 2, a)
```

I expect `[3, 9, 4, 7, 6, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a = [1, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8]
list(map(lambda x: x + 2, a))
```

Comment: Thank you, for working, but why you can explain it

Comment: my friend thank you help me  
I want to learn web2py to do you experience

Comment: Do you have experience web2py